# Deploying an express server alongside a wordpress install on an amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, cloud

I've setup a wordpress site on an amazon ec2 instance. I want to setup an `express` server on that instance as well. These are the steps I followed:

1. Installed npm and node on the cloud
2. Cloned the `express` server code.
3. `npm start`
4. `curl localhost:8080` (returned `Hello world!`)
5. Opened ec2 management console and added a security group with these inbound rules:

   - Custom TCP rule for port 8080 and source `0.0.0.0/0`
   - Custom TCP rule for port 8080 and source `::/0`

The instance had another security group with these inbound rules:

- HTTP rule for port 80
- SSH rule for port 22
- HTTPS rule for port 443

As the step 4 describes, the server is running correctly on the machine. But I'm having trouble accessing the `express` server from outside. I tried these methods:

1. Accessing `<public elastic ip>:8080`
2. Accessing `<blog domain address>:8080`
3. Accessing `<automatically allocated amazon domain>:8080`

All of them fail with `<url> refused to connect` error. All of them redirect to my blog if I leave out the port.

How do I access the server running on my ec2 instance from outside?

Edit: The instance I'm using is a bitnami wordpress install

Comment: are you sure your express server is running on port 8080

Comment: and your ec2 machine is hosted in public subnet